# What is the cmake build directory used by debuild?

Tags: makefile, cmake, debian, packaging, deb

I'm packaging a software ([neko](http://nekovm.org/)) for Debian. The software uses CMake for building. I already have everything setup and it builds nicely. Now, I want to add some additional tests on top of the upstream tests, so I override `dh_auto_test` in `debian/rules` as follows:

```
override_dh_auto_test:
    dh_auto_test
    cd <build_dir> && ./bin/nekotools boot test.n && ./bin/test
```

The problem is that I don't know what is the CMake build directory (`<build_dir>` as written above) thus cannot figure out the paths to the build outputs. Is there a variable that points to the build directory?

Comment: I think more context is needed. In principle there isn't a fixed CMake build directory in relation to the source directory. You pick your build directory and run CMake in it like `cmake [options...] path/to/source`

Comment: I do not call cmake by myself, but let debuild do that. FYI, my rules file can be found at https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/neko-debian/blob/2.1.0-2/debian/rules

Comment: If the rule is correct, the directory where `bin/nekotools` exists ...?

Answer (score 3):

I find out that I can specify the build directory as follows:

```
%:
    dh $@ --builddirectory=foo
```

It is mentioned in the [dh manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dh.1.html).

However, I still would like to know whether there is a variable that stores the build directory even if I'm not using `--builddirectory`...